# Angularjs scope data inside the function

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display the data to my view but `$scope.plan` outputs `{}`. I am thinking that it would output the **fetched data** from the `initGetEdit` **function**, `console.log()` inside the `$http.post` outputs expected data.

**controller.js**

```
var id = $stateParams.id;

$scope.plan = {}

$scope.initGetEdit = function(){
    var data = { id : id }
    $http.post("someUrl", data).then(function(res){
        $scope.plan = res.data;
        console.log($scope.plan); //----> logs expected data
    })
}
$scope.initGetEdit();

console.log($scope.plan);  //----> logs {}
```

In my `view` I have something like this.

**view**

```
<input ng-model="plan.something" type="text" />
```

**UPDATE**

First thank you for those answers provided and the comments, appreciated it. It gives me an insight. I solved my issue by removing the `initGetEdit` **function** and staying with just the `http.post`.

Comment: this is to be expected.  `$http.post` is *asynchronous*, which means the UI does not wait for it to complete before continuing to the next statement.  Therefore, the `console.log()` at the end is reached before the data from the server is returned.  Angular fires a `$digest` after the data is changed, which updates the view, but that has no effect on the `console.log` calls.

Comment: Since `post` is async, `console.log($scope.plan);` at the page end would print empty object. But after sometime, your view would be updated.

Answer (score 2):

Try keeping the second console in watch.

```
$scope.$watch('plan',function(){
  console.log($scope.plan);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, you declare a variable `$scope.plan = {}` after that in `http` call of your `$scope.initGetEdit` function its empty object after the function `http` is an async call your object may be filled based on the response. until that it will be an empty object.

@Ujjwala Bollam mention in answer to print it in the console.

```js
  var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
    app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    //var id = $stateParams.id;
    var id=1;

     $scope.plan = {}

     $scope.initGetEdit = function(){
     var data = { id : id }
    //$http.post("http://someurl", data).then(function(res){
        $scope.plan ={id:1,something:"hai this is response data"};
        console.log($scope.plan); //----> logs expected data
    //})
   }
$scope.initGetEdit();

console.log($scope.plan);  //----> logs {}
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    
    <input ng-model="plan.something" type="text" />
    </div>
```